NGRX Effect erroneously redirects upon completion
I have an NGRX "Feature" set up like this:
Actions:
export const getOrganization = createAction("[Organization] Get");
export const getOrganizationSuccess = createAction("[Organization] Get Success", props<{response: Organization}>());
export const getOrganizationError = createAction("[Organization] Get Error", props<{request: string}>);

Reducers:
on(getOrganizationSuccess, (state, {response})=>{
        console.log("organizationReducer.getOrganizationSuccess")
        return {
            ...state,
            Organization: response
        }
    })

Effects:
export const getOrganizationEffect$ = createEffect(
    (
        actions$ = inject(Actions), 
        service$ = inject(OrganizationService),
        toastService$ = inject(ToastService)
    )=> {
        return actions$.pipe(
            ofType(getOrganization),
            switchMap(()=> {
                return service$.getOrganization().pipe(
                    map((response)=> {
                        console.log("response", response)
                        return getOrganizationSuccess({response: response.Data as Organization})
                    }),
                    catchError(({error})=> {
                        toastService$.sendErrorToasts(error);                        
                        return of(getOrganizationError())
                    })
                )
            })
        )
}, {
    functional: true
});

Component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Organization } from '../models/Organization';
import { organizationSelector } from '../store/organization/organization.selectors';
import { getOrganization } from '../store/organization/organization.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-organization',
  templateUrl: './organization.component.html',
  styleUrl: './organization.component.scss',
  standalone: false
})
export class OrganizationComponent {

  organization$: Observable<Organization | undefined>;

  constructor(
    private readonly store: Store
  ) {
      console.log("OrganizationComponent.constructor")
      this.organization$ = this.store.select(organizationSelector)
    }

  ngOnInit(){
    
    console.log("OrganizationComponent.ngOnInit")
    this.store.dispatch(getOrganization())
  }
}

So, when I log in, I am redirected to the OrganizationComponent, which has a  tag within it.
Organization Html:
<div 
    class="organization-container"
    *ngIf="organization$ | async as organization">
    <div class="left-side panel">
        <app-organization-menu></app-organization-menu>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side panel">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>

And here is the login and logic success effects:
export const loginOrganizationEffect$ = createEffect(
    (
        actions$ = inject(Actions), 
        service = inject(OrganizationService),
        authenticationService = inject(AuthenticationService),
        toastService: ToastService = inject(ToastService)
    )=> {
        return actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loginOrganization),
            switchMap(({request})=> {
                return service.login(request).pipe(
                    map((response)=> {
                        const token: Token = response.Data as Token;
                        authenticationService.SaveToken(token)
                        return loginOrganizationSuccess({response: token})
                    }),
                    catchError(({error})=> {
                        toastService.sendErrorToasts(error);                        
                        return of(loginOrganizationError())
                    })
                )
            })
        )
}, {
    functional: true
});

export const loginOrganizationSuccessEffect$ = createEffect(
    (
        actions$ = inject(Actions), 
        router$ = inject(Router)
    )=> {
        return actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loginOrganizationSuccess),
            tap(()=>{
                console.log("loginOrganizationSuccessEffect$")
                router$.navigateByUrl("organization/dashboard");
            })
        )
}, {
    functional: true,
    dispatch: false
});

Now, I have tried removing the call to dispatch this.store.dispatch(getOrganization()) in OrganizationComponent.ngOnInit.
When I do, the redirect doesn't happen.
Therefore, I believe that this is the call that is somehow causing a redirect.
Perhaps this doesn't have anything to do with angular at all?
My desired effect is that when I log in to the site, I am taken to the organization/dashboard component, then I load the organization's data.
Again, this only happens when I am redirected to the page. It does not happen if I navigate directly to the page.
Any wisdom here would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Update: I went ahead with the suggestion of @Naren Murali (thank you, btw).
Here is the call stack from the getOrganization effect:

SO, I stepped over a few times and ended up here:

This is my LogicComponent class.  It's saying that if we get redirected here, and the token exists, do a redirect to the home page url.
THIS IS WRONG!!!
I screwed up here guys.  I've only been using angular for a few months, so now I know that the proper way to do the redirect is to do it in the effect.
I removed this call to navigate.
Thanks for the support and for the wisdom.

place a debugger point on router$.navigateByUrl("organization/dashboard") and check the stacktrace for the calling order to find the problem, if not possible to solve, please share a stackblitz where the issue happens for debugging
